# Why is a bow always arch-shaped and not of other shape?

Tags: everyday-life

Everytime I see a bow , one thing is greatly noticable- its arch shape. I have never seen bow other than this shape. But what is the cause for taking this shape for the bow? What is the physics behind this??

Comment: i think you wull find these links useful: http://sem-proceedings.com/24i/sem.org-IMAC-XXIV-Conf-s11p03-Mechanics-Simple-Bow.pdf,  http://www.bio.vu.nl/thb/users/kooi/kooi91b.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I actually do some bow-hunting.

First I have to tell you that you aren't completely right about the arc-shape: recursive bows have special curvings near the ends. It requires you to apply less force when you are holding the stretched bow and gives you more time to aim.

Compound bows use levering systems to accomplish the same goal even more efficiently.

The global shape of a bow is actually an arc, but I don't see any surprises there: you have to stretch it and there should be a place for the bowstring after all. But other than that there are no restrictions. Take a look at this great compound bow: [bear motive 6](http://www.lancasterarchery.com/bear-motive-6-compound-bow-realtree-ap.html). Its shape is not exactly an arc is it?